# Product measure: How does this fit together?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I am a bit confused.

Consider $(\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}},\mathcal{B},P)$, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel-$\sigma$-Algebra generated by the cylinder sets of the form
$$
\text{cyl}(y_{i}^{i+n})=\left\{x\in\left\{0,1,2\right\}^{\mathbb{Z}}: x_i=y_i,x_{i+1}=y_{i+1},\ldots,x_{i+n}=y_{i+n}\right\},
$$
and $P$ is a product measure on $\mathcal{B}$, such that
$$
P(\text{cyl}(y_i^{i+n}))=\prod_{k=i}^{i+n}p(y_k), \text{ where} \sum_{k=0}^2 p(k)=1.
$$

---

Now there is the expression
$P\left\{x(0)=1\right\}$.

I do not see how that fits! Because $P$ is a product measure, how can it measure an event like $\left\{x(0)=1\right\}$? Is this event in $\mathcal{B}$?

Comment: Do you mean by$\{x(0)=1\}$ the set$\{(\cdots, x_{-1},x_0,x_1,\cdots)\in\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb Z}: x_0=1\}$?

Comment: The elements of $\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ can be seen as functions from $\mathbb{Z}$ to $\{0,1,2\}$. Then $x(0)$ would be the value at $0\in\mathbb{Z}$. So, $\{x(0)=1\}$ is the set of all elements of $\{0,1,2\}^{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that the entry in the 0-th position is $1$.

Comment: @mac I do not know if the author means that. If yes, it would be a cylinder set and everything would be great. Then this set would simply has measure $p(1)$, right?

Comment: Yes you are right!

Answer (score 0):

The event $x(0)=1$ is a cylinder set. Let $y_k=1$ for all $k\in\Bbb Z$; then the event in question is $\operatorname{cyl}(y_0^0)$.

Comment: Another question: If I have the following dynamics: A 1 becomes a 2 in the next time step, a 2 becomes a 0 and a 0 becomes a 1 if one of its 2 neighbours are 1. By $\eta_n(0)$ denote the state of the position 0 at time $n$. At time $n=0$ let $P$ be the product measure with $p(0)=p(1)=p(2)=1/3$. What is then meant with $\text{Prob}\left\{\eta_n(0)=1\right\})$? Is it meant that $\text{Prob}$ is a NEW product measure with different $p'(0). p'(1)$ and $p'(2)$ that rose by the starting product measure at time $n=0$? Or is $\text{Prob}=P$?

Comment: I am confused, because as far as I see it is $\text{Prob}\left\{\eta_n(0)=1\right\}=P\left\{\eta_0(-n)=1\right\}+P\left\{\eta_0(n)=1\right\}=2p(1)$. But the author claims that $\text{Prob}\left\{\eta_n(0)=1\right\}\sim\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}$. How can that be? It's a long proof, ok. But if it is always $2p(1)$, how can it approximately be like $\sqrt{2/(27\pi n)}$?

Comment: @math12: This is not an area with which I'm very familiar, but yes, that's how I'd interpret it. For instance, it appears that after one step the probability that $x(k)=1$ is $\frac13\cdot\left(1-\left(\frac23\right)^2\right)=\frac5{27}$. The other two probabilities will also change, and that will affect the calculation for the next step. You want to look for a distribution that is stable under the given dynamics.

Comment: Why that?... Do not see that.

Comment: @math12: In order for $x(k)$ to be $1$ after one step, it must initially have been $0$, and at least one of its neighbors must have been $1$.

Comment: And why not the following: $\text{Prob}\left\{\eta_1(0)=1\right\}=P\left\{\eta_0(-1)=1\right\}+P\left\{\eta_0(1)=1\right\}=2p(1)$?

Comment: @math12: I don't see any reason for your suggestion; it doesn't seem to have much to do with the given dynamics.

Comment: If after one step I have a 1 at position 0, then one step before the 1 was at position -1 and/or position 1. So why not calculating the probability by calculating the situation at the step before using the old probability measure P.

Comment: @math12: That doesn't agree with the dynamics that you described in your first comment. First, you've neglected the requirement that $x_0=0$ at $n=0$, and then you've not calculated the probability that at least one of the neighbors was initially $1$.

Comment: Ok, so $\text{Prob}$ seems to mean the product measure after n steps, yes. Ok thanks.

Comment: @math12: That's how I interpret it. You're welcome.

Comment: One last question, please. Consider the event E that there is an adjacent initial (1,2) pair (that is at time 0). Can I write this event as a cylinderset, i.e. $E=\left\{\eta(v)=1, \eta(v')=2\text{ for v and v' adjacent}\right\}$?

Comment: @math12: No, it's a union of cylinder sets, one for each possible position of the adjacent pair. There are only countably many possible positions, though, so that's not a serious problem.

Comment: Disjoint union I guess. So $E=\bigcup_{(i,j)\in Z^2,\text{i and j adjacent}}E_{(i,j)}$. Each $E_{(i,j)}$ has probability $p(1)p(2)$. But the sum then is $\infty$.

Comment: @math12: These cylinder sets aren't pairwise disjoint. The cylinder set at positions $k,k+1$ is disjoint from the one at $k+1,k+2$, but not from any of the ones further to the right, for instance. (I'll be offline for a while now, but I'll be back a bit later.)

Comment: I think I better stop now. :D